# Letters Taking out

Tags: c++

I am looking to create a function that replaces certain letters inside a string array into a letter of my choice, and I am supposed to do this without using any function templates from the c++ library. So far, I have this, but when I printed the output, it doesn't seem to change the array elements. Can someone help me?
A sample array I tried is :

```
string replace[7] = { "gavel" , "apple" , "bear" , "flask" , "festival" , "sacrifice" , "lava" };
```

and  I tried changing the (a)s inside the array into (z)s.

```
int remove(string array1[], int n, char a, char c)
{
    int q = 0;
    int index = 0;
    string s;
    char c = s[index];

    if (n > 1)
    {
        for (q = 0; q < n; q++)
        {
            s = array1[q];
            size_t len = s.size();

            for (index = 0; index < len; index++)
            {
                if (s[index] == a)
                {
                    s[index] == c;
                }
            }
            cout << array1[q] << endl;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eyal Cinamon found your two main issues. You should also consider sticking with a single point of return at the end of your function. Use a return code to indicate success or failure.  Too many exit points from functions can make things a headache to debug.

Comment: okay, i'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Comment: oh sorry it was a mistake, i was trying to rename the variables to make it easier to read my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1. `s = array1[i];` creates a copy of the string. You then continue changing the copy, not the original string in the array.
2. `s[index] == letterToFill;` You mistakenly are using the logical compare, not assignment

Try redefining `s` inside the for loop as a string reference:

```
...
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string& s = array1[i];
...
```

Comment: And a third one: nothing is returned when `n > 1`.

Comment: There's plenty more wrong, but let's just focus on the question :P

Comment: sorry :( , it also says that "string subscript out of range" if I define string& s inside the for loop.

Comment: @lin `string s;` => empty. `char c = s[index];` => out of range, and useless.

Comment: Oh, right, I was more confused on why my array wasn't changing but I will fix that later, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `==` equality operator rather than the assignment operator `=`

```
s[index] == letterToFill;
```

should be

```
s[index] = letterToFill;
```